# Playing video in VB 2022

Tags: visual-studio

In VS2022 I want to play an mp4 video on a user form and it seems I should be using VideoDrawing and MediaPlayer, or possibly MediaElement but I can't create any objects of these types. I suspect I need to add or include something in my project but I can't find what. I can only find C# examples and they imply "it just works".